# Blade is outputting URL encoded characters instead of evaluating inside curly braces

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a link and i used `route()` method but it doesn't get processed to output the link it output a string

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.index') }}">Dashboard</a>
```

***The result***

```
http://web.app/%7B%7B%20route('admin.index')%20%7D%7D
```

Comment: Can you provide the surrounding code? And is the file named something.blade.php ?

Comment: which version of laravel you are using @yasser

Comment: Have your tried using `URL::route()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%20%7D%7D` means PHP converts `{{ }}` characters to HTML entities. It seems you don't use `.blade.php` naming or do something like this. If renaming template won't help, please update your answer with full template contents.